# Indexing array inside an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d array that takes this kind of form:

```
[5643, 22, 0.67, [1.00, 0.05, -0.044....]]
[6733, 12, -0.44, [0.00, 1.00, -0.08...]]
```

so it has dimensions ~13k x 4 but the 4th column of every row is itself an array

what I’d like to do is subset this array such that I only keep the rows for which the yth element of the 4th column is greater than 0

my current approach has been this:

```
mask = [x[y] > 0 for x in array[:,3]]

new_array = array[mask]
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: You could attempt to utilize the `filter` method.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
y = 1

[i for i in filter(lambda x: x[3][y] > 0, a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `if` clause of a list comprehension

```
new_array = [r for r in array if r[3][y] > 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is to not pack arrays in other arrays. This causes many issues, including not being able to use the `shape` attribute of numpy arrays effectively.

So, first split your data into two arrays, one of which has 13k rows, and 3 columns and the other one which also has 13k rows, and the columns of which depends on the dimensionality of the embedded array. Call these `X` and `Y`.

You can then do the following:

```py
# Split the arrays
X, Y = array[:, :3], array[:, 3]
Y = np.asarray(Y)

mask = Y[:, y] > 0
X = X[mask]
```